# Email delivery failure with Email::Sender in Perl

Tags: perl, email

I´m writing a program in Perl wich sends an email to a list of recipients. Once this is done, I would like to print a list of all the recipients and if they got the email or not, like this:
- email@email.com yes
- email2@email.com error
 and so on.

I wrote the code below and it works, sends the emails and an email to the sender if the delivery fails, but I don´t know how can I print the list?

```
use Email::Simple::Creator; # or other Email:: 
while (<lista_direcciones>) {
    #En $_ está cada una de las direcciones

my $message = Email::Simple->create(
    header => [
        From    => $dir_origen,
        To      => $_,
        Subject => $asunto,
    ],
    body => $contenido,
);

try {       
    sendmail($message, { transport => $transport });
} catch {
    warn "Sending failed: $_";
};      
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you want to collect emails for which sending failed?

Answer (score 2):

Just put them in a hash and save the result. Afterwards, iterate over that hash and print the results.

```
my %addresses;

while (<lista_direcciones>) {

  #En $_ está cada una de las direcciones

  my $message = Email::Simple->create(
    header => [
      From    => $dir_origen,
      To      => $_,
      Subject => $asunto,
    ],
    body => $contenido,
  );

  try {
    sendmail( $message, { transport => $transport } );
    $addresses{$_} = 1;
  }
  catch {
    $addresses{$_} = 0;
    warn "Sending failed: $_";
  };
}

foreach $to ( keys %addresses ) {
  printf "%s: %s\n", $to, $addresses{$to} ? 'yes' : 'no';
}
```

Or you could just put a `print` next to where you are sending the mail.

```
try {
  sendmail( $message, { transport => $transport } );
  print "$_ yes\n";
}
catch {
  warn "Sending failed: $_";
  print "$_ no\n";
};
```